# Trying to pass variable to URL in the edit link of show results

Tags: php, variables, url, get

I have a show results page dumping the contents of a table. I've managed to echo in an edit link on each of my table rows. Edit kicks user to an update records page.

I'm trying to include the variables from the table row to the edit URL so I can do a `$_GET` URL param function on the update page and propagate the update form.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```html
   echo "<table>";
   /* Get field information for all fields */
   while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_object($queryResult))
   { 
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row->band_name . "</td><td>" . $row->votes . "</td><td><a href='vote.html?$band_name&$votes'>Edit</a></td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, make sure that you declare your variables properly. It seems these guys are undefined in your url:

```
$band_name&$votes
```

Then format your url properly:

```
while ($row =  mysqli_fetch_object($queryResult))
{
    $band_name = $row->band_name;
    $votes = $row->votes;   
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "
            <td>$band_name</td>
            <td>$votes</td>
            <td>
                <a href='vote.html?band_name=".urlencode($band_name)."&votes=$votes'>Edit</a>
            </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Are you sure its `<a href='vote.html`? HTML? you won't be able to parse this properly. Change it to `vote.php`

Then in `vote.php`, just get those values thru `$_GET`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['band_name'], $_GET['votes'])) {
    $band_name = $_GET['band_name'];
    $votes = $_GET['votes'];

    // rest of code mysqli etc. etc.
}

?>
```

Comment: This is really helpful - thanks! First part implemented and working, second part I don't really know how to implement this in vote.php so the variables propogate into the update form. Any further help would be appreciated (otherwise, I'll keep messing with javascript to sort it out). Thanks again!

Comment: @pxlkllr the next step is creating that `vote.php`. and then just using the code above, of course the remaining logic is up to you. the code above was to get the `band name, votes` values so that you could use that to further do processing, like editing and other stuff.

Comment: ah, so if I echo form elements in vote.php, I can pop in the variables directly, instead of using JS to decode the URL params and pass them to the form fields on the html doc? Am I on the right track?

Comment: @pxlkllr yes you don't need to js from here, when oyu click the edit link, it should redirect it to `vote.php` where you transport those values, then just create your form there, setup the fields then make the update query also from there

Comment: No errors, but a blank screen. I think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong:

Comment: timer ran out - let's try this (although it looks like pre tags only partially useful...http://www.pxlkllr.com/php/example.html

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear on exactly what is not working, but in order for PHP to be able to get the query params they have to have a name.

if you change the following line and add parameter names, you should be able to access the data with $_GET or parse_str.

```
      echo "<td>" . $row->band_name . "</td><td>" . $row->votes . "</td><td><a href='vote.html?band_name=$band_name&votes=$votes'>Edit</a></td>";
```